# Backspace doesn't work in sqlplus command line

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

In my sqlplus (for oracle) command line, the backespace doesn't work. How could I configure sqlplus for deleting characters from the command line with backspace? I don't use frequently sqlplus command line, only for making quickly interventions in my DB, it is very hazard for me the times I need to use.

Kind Regards. Thanks

Comment: ctrl-h normally works as backspace on most Unixes I have run sqlplus on.

Comment: ctrl + backspace worked with me on RHEL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which platform are you working on?

in case it's linux, have a look at [this section of a wikipedia article on the bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29#Keyboard_shortcuts) for some keyboard shortcuts. you should be able to navigate the sqlplus command line with the same shortcuts when you call sqlplus from the shell (bash). specifically, `ctrl-b` would be backspace.

Comment: It is Solaris (Unix) Thanks

Comment: Are you using the korn shell (ksh) ? [This SO post'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623256/make-arrow-and-delete-keys-work-in-kornshell-command-line)s accepted answer shows how to make backspace (and some other keys) work, which should carry through to sqlplus as well. the z shell behaves similarly to the bash according to [this cheat sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davidsouther/cheat-sheets/bash-zsh-shourtcuts/).

Answer (score 14):

Following the instructions [here](http://www.beyondoracle.com/2008/10/22/improve-sqlplus-before-you-get-crazy/) I was able to do the following and get this working:

1. Type `stty erase` in the terminal
2. Press `CTRL+v` on your keyboard
3. Press the `Backspace Key` on the keyboard (when I did this it put `^H` on the line so my final line looked like `stty erase ^H`)
4. Press enter

Now if I start up sql plus I can use the backspace key to delete mistyped characters.

Comment: It worked in RHEL 6.5. Thanks. Added it in /etc/profile for it to work everytime.

Comment: Thanks again. I saw this and clicked to vote up and it says I already voted up in 2016.  It was a good answer then, it is a good answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your suggestions. In other forums I have found this workaround:

I have used stty -a for watching I/O settings: And I could see erase is set to ^?

So for setting the backspace for deleting characters I have set stty erase ^H, and then works for the session.

Thanks.