# tab and arrow keys weird behavior in redhat

Tags: linux, terminal, iterm2, arrow-keys, tab-completion

I am facing some weird behavior when trying to ssh to the server by using either `Iterm2` or OSX `Terminal`. Basically, the issue is when using `tab` for auto-completion, it will print one more random extra char in the end, for example:

```
//the 'e' is extra in this case
$ cd keys/e
```

And when trying to use any arrow keys for navigation, it basically does not work at all.

```
//^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C are printed by pressing arrow keys
$ cd keys/^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[Ce

//Kernel Version
OS Version: 2.6.39-400.246.2.el6uek.x86_64

//Distribution Information
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)
```

But it works just fine in my macbook, I was guessing it is caused by my server profile setting up, but I have double-checked that I do not have either of the following files in my home:

```
$ vi .bash_profile
$ vi .bashrc
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The question is unclear because `^[[C` (right-arrow) is not used for "navigation" in the shell.  You may be finding some problems with mismatch of terminal and `TERM` setting, but there are no details to help people answer.

Comment: When I am saying `navigation`, I mean navigating in between the characters I have typed on the command like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had it figured out, it is because of my default shell in the server is `ksh`, need to ask the system admin to change it to `bash` or `zsh`.

Answer (score 1):

What you termed "navigation" is part of line-editing.

If you're using `ksh`, the way to best use its line-editing capabilities is to turn on emacs mode:

```
set -o emacs
```

Apparently ksh's developer doesn't use `vi`, because the vi-mode is very limited.  However, `emacs` mode is the default.

In your question, the cursor-keys are in *normal mode* (the `^[[` characters), which is assumed if `TERM=linux`, while other terminals conventionally use *application mode* (`^[O` characters).  If your `TERM` is set incorrectly, that might confuse `ksh`.  Some people define aliases in their shell initialization to make the shell work with either.

See for example *[Make Arrow and delete keys work in KornShell command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623256/make-arrow-and-delete-keys-work-in-kornshell-command-line)*.  The solutions in that answer should work for you, since RHEL6 (and CentOS6) use ksh-93:

```
Name        : ksh                          Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 20120801                          Vendor: CentOS
Release     : 28.el6_7.3                    Build Date: Tue Sep 22 11:08:59 2015
Install Date: Mon Mar 28 16:22:50 2016         Build Host: c6b9.bsys.dev.centos>
Group       : System Environment/Shells     Source RPM: ksh-20120801-28.el6_7.3>
Size        : 1743023                          License: EPL
Signature   : RSA/SHA1, Tue Sep 22 14:35:03 2015, Key ID 0946fca2c105b9de
Packager    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>
URL         : http://www.kornshell.com/
Summary     : The Original ATT Korn Shell
Description :
KSH-93 is the most recent version of the KornShell by David Korn of
AT&T Bell Laboratories.
KornShell is a shell programming language, which is upward compatible
with "sh" (the Bourne Shell).
```

Further reading:

- [2.1 Enabling Command-line Editing](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/ksh/ch02_01.htm) (Learning the Korn Shell)
- [Command Line Editing in Bash and Ksh](http://www.phcomp.co.uk/Tutorials/Unix-And-Linux/Bash-and-Korn-shell-history-reference.html) notes

  > Some actions are also bound to keys with special markings, eg: *Up Arrow*, *Del* (or *Delete*). These are also shown where applicable. Note that these might not work if the terminal emulation is incorrect, `ksh` does not support them as well as does `bash`.