# AIX - Default shell - Arrow keys

Tags: linux, terminal, aix

I am using AIX machine. I have a concern.  I use MobaXterm to access the AIX server. I expected the upward arrow key to give me the previously issued command. Instead it simply goes up as  in some editor. The same behavior is observed with down arrow key. How can I get rid of this behaviour?

The shell is ksh.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use `bash` instead of `ksh`

Comment: It works. But when I echo $SHELL it  gives ksh. Is it correct?

Comment: Use a script like this: `export SHELL=$(which bash); exec bash`

Comment: Using bash is a good workaround. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll see that sort of behavior when the terminal sends normal-mode cursor keys.  `ksh` may be looking for application-mode keys, or (more likely) hasn't been told how to handle this.  You may get it to work using

```
set -o emacs
```

but may also need to establish key-bindings (found in the first link):

```
#
# The ksh has an undocumented way of binding the arrow keys to the emacs
# line editing commands. In your .kshrc or in your .profile, add:

alias __A=`echo "\020"` # up arrow = ^p = back a command
alias __B=`echo "\016"` # down arrow = ^n = down a command
alias __C=`echo "\006"` # right arrow = ^f = forward a character
alias __D=`echo "\002"` # left arrow = ^b = back a character
alias __H=`echo "\001"` # home = ^a = start of line

# Type "set -o emacs" or put this line in your .profile.
set -o emacs
```

In a quick check, this works for me, with normal-mode keys.

Further reading:

- [aixterm and arrow keys - AIX](https://web.archive.org/web/20131002175122/http://www.justskins.com/forums/aixterm-and-arrow-keys-211045.html)
- [AIX : retrieving previous command using up arrow](https://superuser.com/questions/182532/aix-retrieving-previous-command-using-up-arrow)
- [Make Arrow and delete keys work in KornShell command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623256/make-arrow-and-delete-keys-work-in-kornshell-command-line)
- [My cursor keys do not work](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#cursor_appmode) (ncurses FAQ)

Answer (score 0):

1. `$SHELL` is the right variable to check what kind of shell you are running. `$1` is used in shell scripts in order to retrieve the first argument you passed to that script. I don't know why is printing `sh` to be honest.